# Using a Speech Recognizer and TTS manager class

Tags: android, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I'm trying to have this central manager class that handles the speech recognition and output voice data. So far, I have failed. This is what the class looks like but my app crashes when I try implementing it in other classes. Can someone please help me out?

Cheers!

```
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;

public class speechEngineR extends Activity {

SpeechRecognizer ears;
TextToSpeech tts; 
Intent i; 
Context mCon = null; 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ears = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(mCon); 
    i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, mCon.getPackageName()); 

    tts = new TextToSpeech(mCon, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR){
                tts.setLanguage(Locale.US); 
            }
        }
    });


    ears.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle results) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int error) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onEndOfSpeech() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}

public speechEngineR(Context c){
    mCon = c; 
}

public void outSpeech(String out){
    tts.speak(out, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null); 
}


}
```

And yes, I have I added the following permission in the Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question and code does not help.

In your code it seems you are trying to use Speech to Text(Audio recorder), and you are calling it using TTS (Text to Speech) which does exactly the opposite of what you are trying to accomplish i.e. speech to text.

Can you make it a bit more clear what you are trying to do??

Comment: What I'm trying to do is basically have a central VR and TTS class. I want to use these 2 classes(VR and TTS) by calling it from the central class speechEngineR instead of calling it over and over again.

Comment: When you do Speech to Text...store it in a string and put that string in a field..

Comment: When you want to do Text to speech..pass A string to TTS and it would synthesize voice for your string... Also if you are trying to run this on emulator, Voice recorder won't work...you need to test that feature on actual device

Comment: Okay. But how do I go about implementing it in other classes? Just the TTS for now.

Comment: You can update your class(speechEngineR)which implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener and implement necessary methods instead of doing it directly in Activity. After that, you initialize tts object in the class where you want to use TTS by calling it like tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new speechEngineR());

Comment: Didn't seem to work. This is what my code looks like:

t = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new speechEngineO());  
  
  t.speak("Welcome!", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

Comment: What is the error?? and what is speechEngineO isn't it speechEngineR??

Comment: if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
     t.speak("Welcome", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);      

   }